# Trouble removing sprites from parent node

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm making an endless running game in which users dodge obstacles, and I'm working on producing the obstacles right now. The plan I had where I'm spawning these obstacles is as follows:

```
obstacle->setPosition(CCPointMake(this->getContentSize().width, this->getContentSize().height*.75)); 
obstacle->setScale(.5);
this->addChild(obstacle);
_obstacles->addObject(obstacle);
obstacle->runAction(CCMoveBy::create(2.0, CCPointMake(-(this->getContentSize().width + obstacle->getContentSize().width/2), 0)));
obstacle->removeFromParent();
```

I set the position, set it's scale, add it to the scene, run an action on it so that it moves across the screen from right to left, add it to an array called _obstacles to be used elsewhere, and then I remove it from the scene so as to save memory. However, the problem is that once I try implement this, the obstacle doesn't show up at all as if it's nowhere to be seen. When I don't call `obstacle->removeFromParent()` it shows up and performs the action. What am I doing wrong here? If I don't call `removeFromParent()`, what do I call? Is there a problem in my code not related to `removeFromParent()`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that obstacle doesn't apeear at all is that it is removed as it start moving. You just have to create a sequence of move action and function call with obstacle as parameter and than remove this obstacle in that function , so that obstacle will be removed after moving out of screen.

```
CCCallFuncN *myCallFunc   =   CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(CLASS_NAME::removeObstacles));
    obstacle->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCMoveBy::create(2.0, CCPointMake(-(this->getContentSize().width + obstacle->getContentSize().width/2), 0)),myCallFunc,NULL));
```

Method to remove obstacle from array and from parent view

```
void CLASS_NAME::removeObstacles(CCObject* pSender){
    // Type cast pSender to obstacle type e.g if obstacle is of CCSprite type.
    CCSprite *tempObstacle = (CCSprite *)pSender;
    _obstacle.pop_back(tempObstacle);
    tempObstacle->removeFromParent();
}
```

Don't forget to replace CLASS_NAME by your class name

Comment: This brought up an exception.

Comment: what exception you are getting exactly?

Answer (score -2):

I would need more info on what removeFromParent is doing and how you use _obstacles

I'm taking a guess on how the parent is structured.  I would guess that it has a list of children and when the parent is updated/render, it calls those functions for its children.  If removeFromParent removes the object from its parent list, then that would explain why it is not being render or used in the scene.  If you have a setup like this, then you should only call removeFromParent before destroying the parent object